# Get auto generated id at time of insertion in Apache Derby database.

Tags: sql, derby

or is there any way of auto-generating Foreign Key in another table i.e. normalized table?

```
    createConnection();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("insert into PRODUCTS(PRODUCTNAME, PURCHASEPRICE, RETAILPRICE, QUANTITY) values ( '"+product.getProductName()+"',"+product.getPurchasePrice()+","+product.getRetailPrice()+","+product.getQuantity()+")");
            stmt.close();
            shutdown();
```

Comment: Possible SQL Injection. Use prepared statement instead of concatenating SQL string

Comment: Are you asking how to use Statement.getGeneratedKeys?